# React Js too much recursion when I tried to change a state in reducer.

Tags: reactjs, recursion, redux

I have two containers, which are `menu_container` and `add_on_container`. Each container has several components. These two containers are mounted in `view` file.

In my reducer, I have a state `showAddOn`. So what I want to make is that depends on the state `showAddOn`, it shows either `menu_container` or `add_on_container`

To do that in each container, I wrote code like

//`AddOnContainer`

```
  render () {
     if(showAddOn == true) {
       return false;
     }
     else return (
          <div>
             My Components....
          </div>
       );
```

//`MenuContainer`

```
  render () {
     if(showAddOn == false) {
       return false;
     }
     else return (
          <div>
             My Components....
          </div>
       );
```

But it triggers `too much recursion` when I tried to dispatch an action to change state `showAddOn`

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in **View** container like this:

```
render() {
   {showAddOn ? <MenuContainer /> : <AddOnContainer /> }
}
```

This will load only one component, depending on condition.